# Building dynamic forms from models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following model in models.py

```
class TProfiles(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'profiles'
```

And in my template I want to produce a form based on the model attributes. Is there a way of looping through them dynamically?

**register.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <!-- Loop through model attributes here -->
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: create a 'modelForm' and pass it to template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `models.py` add:

```
class TProfilesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TProfiles
        fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'email']
```

And in `views.py` create form like this:

```
form = TProfilesForm()
```

Then pass it to template like this:

```
return render_to_response("register.html", {
    "form": form,
})
```

And in template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also you can find all about `ModelForm` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Do you know how to ignore certain fields? I have an ID field that I wouldn't like to appear on the form.